# `add` but with "mutating" properties, like `push`

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a default method in jQuery that allows adding elements to stack without reassigning variable?

For now I'm always doing - `$stack = $stack.add($element);`, but I hate that reassignment all the times.

Is there something like [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for jQuery?

P.S. Yes, I know I can make a extension, just wondering about default method.

Comment: By "stack" you mean some jQuery collection?

Comment: Does this look like what you need? http://api.jquery.com/pushstack/

Comment: @JustinM nope. that will have the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately pushStack is the mechanism used internally by `$.add()` to create a new set of objects.  pushStack is also used by map, find, filter, and other methods as jQuery's MO is to create a new result set and leave the original object unaltered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something like `Array.prototype.push` for jQuery?

No, not "something like". There *is* [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) available on the [jQuery prototype](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/7e8a91c205723f11cd00c8834f348a649ab15926/src/core.js#L114)

```
var push = [].push;
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    …
    // For internal use only.
    // Behaves like an Array's method, not like a jQuery method.
    push: push,
    …
};
```

Notice that it is not chainable, but returns the `length` of the collection.

Comment: `.push()` isn't a documented part of the API, so I wouldn't suggest using it. [`.pushStack()`](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/) may be better for this.

Comment: @cookiemonster: True, but that depends on the use case (and `pushStack` is non-mutating as well). You're right about "*internal use only*", but even if that would change you could easily deploy a "plugin" `$.fn.push=[].push;` :-)

Comment: Yeah, a plugin is probably the safest in that case.